# How to show preview of documents within the app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to show the preview of the files within the app but I am not getting the exact way to do that meanwhile I am showing the preview by using other application with the below code

```
           File file = new File(filePath);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            String fileExtension = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            fileExtension = fileExtension.toLowerCase();
            if(mimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension) != null) {
                String type = mimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension);
                String fp = "file//"+filePath.substring(4);
                if(isTablet(activity))
                {
                    if(fileExtension.equals("txt"))
                    {
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/plain");    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
                }                   

                try{
                    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_AUTHENTICATION_COMPLETED);
                }catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e){
                    System.out.println("exception : "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }                   
            }
```

This working fine but now I want to show the preview of supported file within the app. I know that QLPreview view controller is there for iOS and I have also referred "[What is the counterpart of iOS' QLPreviewController or UIDocumentInteractionController on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330711/what-is-the-counterpart-of-ios-qlpreviewcontroller-or-uidocumentinteractioncont)" but no luck so Please assist me on this.....Thanks in advance

Comment: this is not possible in Android.

Comment: I have seen in box app it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no build in class like QLPreviewController in andriod but I have handled it manually by reading the file content from the path and then displaying the content into the App.